# Requirements for custom annotation processing?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

Consider a basic Java program where the goal is to create a custom parameter-validating annotation.

Most other examples of this code focus on its usage within Spring or Hibernate, but is this possible in a plain-old Java program? The example code below does not call the custom annotation at all. Breakpoints inside of `MinLengthValidator` don't get hit.

The javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final jar is on the classpath, as is org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.1.Final FWIW, but I would have thought that was only necessary for use with the built-in bean validation annotations, not a custom one.

Within Eclipse, I have turned on Annotation Processing via the Java Compiler settings, and included a class which implements `AbstractProcessor`, marked with `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.MinLength")`, but its `process` method doesn't seem to be invoked either.

What else is required? Compiler flags, JVM options? Is there a canonical reference for the use of the validation annotation API within "plain vanilla" Java projects?

=====

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printLongMessage("hello today is Wednesday");
}

public static void printLongMessage(@MinLength(5) String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

The `@MinLength` validation is provided by the following two classes:

MinLength.java:

```
package com.example;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target( { PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE } )
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MinLengthValidator.class)
public @interface MinLength {

    String message() default "String is shorter than allowed minimum length.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int value();
}
```

MinLengthValidator.java:

```
package com.example;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class MinLengthValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MinLength, String> {

    private int minLength;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MinLength constraintAnnotation) {
        minLength = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value.length() >= minLength;
    }
}
```